# Why is the regex invalid in javascript? /(?i)-StringA$|-StringB$/

Tags: javascript, regex

Built this regex in a generator, everything works as expected, tried it in my app for cleaning up some strings, app says its invalid.

Its declared as follows:

```
const reg = /(?i)-TeamMember$|-TeamLead$/;
testString = testString.replace(reg, "");
```

Attempting to run the app yields this:

```
Module parse failed: Invalid regular expression: /(?i)-StringA$|-StringB$/: Invalid group (199:21)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Tried this in a generator, everything works as expected, goal is to remove a suffix from a string if it matches either of the strings provided and ignores case.

Comment: Javascript does not support inline modifiers `(?i)` You can use the `/i` flag for case insensitive

Comment: _Inline Modifier (?i)
In .NET, PCRE (C, PHP, R…), Perl, Python, Java and Ruby (but not JavaScript), you can use the inline modifier (?i). In JavaScript, your only option is to add the i flag after your pattern's closing delimiter._

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have a built-in case-insensitive inline flag. Instead, you should use the case-insensitive flag `/i`

```
const reg = /-TeamMember$|-TeamLead$/i;
testString = testString.replace(reg, "");
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/ignoreCase